# Loop Work for only one time as i set it should work twice or more

Tags: php, loops

I created a loop and store value in array and then foreach for send a mail threw it but it only works once and after that not work and i also tried if email id was not searched in mail should not go but didn't find any error but also the code is also not working

i also tried too many codes but not work

```
// run query
$query = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT email FROM login where  id='248' OR id='241' OR id='247' "));

// set array
$array = array();


    // add each row returned into an array
    $array[] = $query['email']; 


    foreach ($array as $item) {

 $user['email'] = $item;

    $search_history = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"select user_id,search_name from search_history HAVING  user_id = '".$user['email']."' ORDER BY id DESC limit 5"));
        $product_keyword = $search_history['search_name'] ."Products";
        $product_keyword1 = $search_history['search_name'];
        $user_id1 = $search_history['user_id'];

        $products = '<table align="left" class="em_wrapper" width="560" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">';

        $qry="select * from add_new_product WHERE keyword LIKE '%$product_keyword1%' AND status=1 ORDER BY pro_id DESC LIMIT 12 ";
        $res=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
```

Comment: Have a look at the [manual examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples) (especially the 1st one), the way you are using the loop is totally incorrect.

Comment: Would an SQL Join not make your life easier.
As your simply searching for emails that match a specific set of ID numbers

"SELECT history.search_name, history.userID, login.email FROM login INNER JOIN search_history AS history ON history.userID=login.email WHERE login.id='123' OR login.id='345' or login.id='927'"

Also I agree with @Dharman
You need to use Php Data Objects to prevent SQL injection

Comment: @DataCure I do not agree with you. You do not need to use PHP Data Objects to prevent SQL injection. As my comment said you need to use Prepared Statements which are available in most DB drivers including MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: @Dharman My bad i only skimmed your post and noticed it was about SQL injections and I agreed the query wasnt using prepared statements, I always use PDO hence my reply, but I will asume your right as I dont use mysqli_connect anymore

Answer (score -2):

**Sumary:**
From reading your code, your attempting to obtain the email field from the login table where it matches with id numbers 241 247 248

As you need the email column as an array in order to perform a secondary SQL search targeting "search_history" table.

A simpler method would be to perform an SQL join
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Which will then return all results where login.id = email

That then frees you up to loop thru the results and carry out what would be your 3rd SQL statement

I noticed the following 3 variables are defined in your code but never used in the snippet you provided

$products

$product_keyword

$user_id1

```
<?PHP
    echo "Stackoverflow Question ID: 57243466\n";
    echo "<hr>";
    $Username = "root";
    $Password = "":
    $Host = "localhost";
    $databaseName = "my_database";

    try{
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $Host . ";dbname=" . $databaseName, $Username, $Password]);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT history.search_name, history.userID, login.email FROM login RIGHT JOIN search_history AS history ON history.userID=login.email WHERE login.id='248' OR login.id='241' or login.id='247'";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->execute();

        foreach($stmt as $item){

            //Please note you have not made any use of the following variable declarations in your code uncomment the lines beneath if you do need to use them.
            //$product_keyword = $item['search_name'] ."Products";
            //$user_id1 = $item['user_id'];

            $products = '<table align="left" class="em_wrapper" width="560" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center">';       

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM add_new_product WHERE keyword LIKE %:product_keyword1% AND status=1 ORDER BY pro_id DESC LIMIT 12 ";
            $res = $con->prepare($sql);
            $res->execute(["product_keyword1"=>$item['search_name']);

            foreach($res as $i){
                // do something with the SQL Query you have performed
            }
    }
}catch(exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Few points to consider. 1)The question uses MySQLi not PDO. This solution would not work for them unless they change the DB extension. 2) When opening new PDO connection you should always specify the charset in DSN, without it you could still be vulnerable to SQL injection in rare cases.  3) `'%:product_keyword1%'` is a quoted string, not a placeholder. 4) You should not be catching exceptions. Leave them as they are, or if you really want only catch the connection exception. 5) You have 3 syntax errors! I recommend you use a proper IDE with syntax check.